# libvlcsharp error in xamarin.forms project

Tags: xamarin.forms, libvlcsharp

my code:

```
private void Initialize()
        {            
            LibVLCSharp.Shared.Core.Initialize();// error here

        }
```

the error notify:
LibVLCSharp.Shared.VLCException: 'failed to load libc++_shared exception dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libc++_shared.so" needed or dlopened by "/apex/com.android.art/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"
How should I do?

Comment: Have you installed the Nuget an all the projects incluiding the ios and Android?

Comment: Missing LibVLC.Android nuget